# Convert PHP variable into Javascript Variable with escaping character

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, escaping

I've been trying to convert a php variable into a java script variable. At the same time I want to save it in a format with HTML tags. The problem is I'm Unable to escape the '<' this character in code.

```
 var lecturers = [
     @foreach ($Lecturers as $L)
       '{{ '<option>'.$L->Name.'</option>' }}',
     @endforeach
 ];
```

The Output I received through console log is as follows

```
["&lt;option&gt;&lt;/option&gt;", "&lt;option&gt;&lt;/option&gt;", "&lt;option&gt;&lt;/option&gt;"]
```

How can i get the output as

```
"<option> Name </option>"
```

I'm using laravel as Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `{!! !!}` instead to avoid escaping:

```
var lecturers = [
     @foreach ($Lecturers as $L)
       '{!! '<option>'.$L->Name.'</option>' !!}',
     @endforeach
 ];
```

Comment: That was brilliant. Thank you.